# JMeter: LoggingCSSParseErrorHandler: Browser compliant mode skipped CSS

Tags: jmeter

JMeter version 4.0

I have the following error in jmeter.log

```
WARN c.h.c.r.e.LoggingCSSParseErrorHandler: Browser compliant mode skipped CSS from [xx:xx] starting at token ' ' until [xx:xx] to token ';' (based on com.helger.css.parser.ParseException: Encountered unexpected token: ")" ")"
    at line xx, column xx.

Was expecting one of:

    "+"
    "-"
)
```

I don't want to disable css parser in jmeter.properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore such exceptions using JMeter property, set it in user.properties:

```
 css.parser.ignore_all_css_errors=true
```

> # Let the CSS Parser ignore all css errors
>
> #css.parser.ignore_all_css_errors=true

Comment: But shouldn't we try to find the cause of the Error?

Comment: @kamal it should be fixed since 5.1.1 , can you verify? https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63674